# Datatables ajax for sorting by different parameter

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using datatables jquery plugin and the AJAX method. My AJAX returns something similar to the following:

```
[
["1463","Example title 1",{"display":"02\/03\/2015 12:15:00","timestamp":"1425297601"},1,"1",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
["1462","Example title 2",{"display":"02\/03\/2015 11:45:00","timestamp":"1425295802"},1,"1",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
["1461","Example title 3",{"display":"02\/03\/2015 11:30:00","timestamp":"1425295220"},1,"1",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
]
```

Where it should display the first value in field 2 but sort by the second. This works fine when the data is provided to the table on page load, but not in an ajax call.

My HTML/Script for the table is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {                
        $('#resultsLatestPosts').DataTable({
                dom: 'T<"clear">frtip',
                autoWidth: false,
                iDisplayLength: 50,
                scrollY: "420px",
                paging: false,
                tableTools: {sSwfPath:'/includes/js/DataTables-1.10.4/extensions/TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf',aButtons:["copy","xls","pdf"]},                
                ajax: 'index.php?ajax=1&function=getLatestPosts',
                ajaxDataProp: '',                                                      
        })
})
</script>

<table id="resultsLatestPosts" class="display">
  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>Post Title</th>
  <th>Sent</th>
  <th>Accounts Sent to</th>
  <th>Posts Sent</th>
  <th>Social Leads</th>
  <th><img src="/images/icons/vendor_postdetails/download-icon-32.png" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" alt="Downloads" title="Downloads" /><span style="display:none">Downloads</span></th>
  <th><img src="/images/icons/vendor_postdetails/followers-icon-32.png" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" alt="Connections" title="Connections" /><span style="display:none">Connections</span></th><th><img src="/images/icons/vendor_postdetails/retweet-icon-32.png" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" alt="Retweets" title="Retweets" /><span style="display:none">Retweets</span></th>
  <th><img src="/images/icons/vendor_postdetails/like-icon-32.png" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" alt="Likes" title="Likes" /><span style="display:none">Likes</span></th>
  <th><img src="/images/icons/vendor_postdetails/favourite-icon-32.png" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" alt="Favourites" title="Favourites" /><span style="display:none">Favourites</span></th>
  <th><img src="/images/icons/vendor_postdetails/reply-icon-32.png" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" alt="Comments/Replies" title="Comments/Replies" /><span style="display:none">Comments/Replies</span></th>
  <th><img src="/images/icons/vendor_postdetails/extended-followers-icon-32.png" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" alt="Extended Reach" title="Extended Reach" /><span style="display:none">Extended Reach</span></th></tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

To clarify. If my json was returning:

```
["1463","Test post",{"render":{"display":"02\/03\/2015 12:15:00","filter":"1425297601"}},1,"1",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

How can I mimic the sorting actions found here:
https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render#object

Please can someone explain what I'm missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me as though you are misunderstanding where the `render` is supposed to be.

You should instead use:

```
$('#resultsLatestPosts').DataTable({
                ... snip
                render: {
                      "filter": "filter",
                      "display": "display"
                       }                                                
                });
```

and your JSON should be along these lines:

```
["1463","Test post", "display":"02\/03\/2015 12:15:00","filter":"1425297601",1,"1",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

See the [examples](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render#Examples)

Note: none of this is tested and I haven't used this portion of DataTables.